# gaussian distribution endurance test

Tags: unbalanced-classes, lognormal-distribution

I am conducting an endurance test experiment on spare parts. I put these part under stress for long hours to see when they start failing. I have a total amount of 42 spare parts.

1 part failed at run-time between 1000 and 1500 hours
4 parts failed  part failed between 1500 and 2000 hours
2 parts failed between 2000 and 2500hours
35 parts finished the endurance run at 2500h without defect

Assuming failure curve is log-normal distributed is there a way to infer the possible mean and standard deviation of such a curve from the information given? The issue I have is that my dataset is imbalanced with all sample coming from the leftmost portion of the left tail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have rephrased the question. I hope I am clear. Not a native speaker here.

Comment: Why do you think the data follows the Gaussian distribution? From your description nothing seems to suggest this.

Comment: The part design expert think so. It may not indeed.

Comment: Do you have some data? Can you show us a plot?